# Cómo obtener la duración de un video en php

Tags: php8

Necesito saber si es posible obtener la duración de una archivo video en php, por que necesito validar que los videos no sobrepasen los 90 segundos los cuales publicó la api de facebook para los reels

Comment: Tendrías que tener la extensión de FFmpeg instalada en tu servidor web antes Con eso podrías conseguir en la documentación oficial la manera de como tomar el tiempo de duración

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].